# How to split 1D array into 2D array in NumPy by splitting the array at the last element?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array, say

```
 ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

I want to split it into a 2d array such that the last element is in its own array, like this

```
 ([1,2,3,4,5,6],[7])
```

How exactly would I do this?

Comment: BTW that's not a 2D array, just two separate 1D arrays or lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) -

```
np.split(a,[-1])
```

Sample run -

```
In [105]: a
Out[105]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

In [106]: np.split(a,[-1])
Out[106]: [array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), array([7])]
```